# Image Comparison in an android

Tags: android, face-recognition, image-comparison

I have requirement like below in an android,

Read image from camera or gallery of android phone.
Compare this image with an image stored in a database (any valid format).
Show the percentage of match between the images.

Tell me possible ways to achieve it.

Comment: Please share code you have tried

Comment: @Sharan can check this link and get back to me https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images#Java

Comment: Definitely possible, using different ML models

Comment: yes also check @WebInsight Comment.. It will Help You.

Comment: @Weblnsight  i tried that but issue is i have images with different size

Comment: @LalitVerma can you give me more description

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2016/06/android-image-recognition-google-cloud-vision-api/ you can use this api for both images and compare data for your simillarity criteria

Answer (score 0):

First You Have To Compare Image Height And Width .. if It is Same then You Have To compare Bytes Pixel.

**Check Height And Width.**

```
if (image1.getHeight() != image2.getHeight()){
 return false;
}
 if (image1.getWidth() != image2.getWidth()){
 return false;
}
```

**Then Check Image Pixel**

```
for (int i = 0; i < image1.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image1.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            if (image1.getPixel(i,j) == image2.getPixel(i,j))
            {
               // Do whatever you want Correct Image.. // both image Are Same
            }
            else
            {
                // both image Are diffrent
            }
        }
    }
```

**Full Code Look Like**

```
if (image1.getHeight() != image2.getHeight()){
    isImageSame = false;
    return;
}
if (image1.getWidth() != image2.getWidth()){
    isImageSame = false;
    return;
}


if(isImageSame){

for (int i = 0; i < image1.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image1.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            if (image1.getPixel(i,j) == image2.getPixel(i,j))
            {
               // Do whatever you want Correct Image.. // both image Are Same
            }
            else
            {
                // both image Are diffrent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you Can Also Do it By **OpenCV lib**
also find Good Example here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/face-detection

Comment: @SharanBallundagi Please Add All Description about your Image And Some Code In Your Question So People Will Able To give Suitable  Answer of your Question.